# Does an external eGPU or GPU take the lag in blender away while working in the UI?

Tags: modeling, rendering, interface

I have a IMAc with the M1 chip, but when working with some more complicated models the UI render lag is getting pretty annoying. does a eGPU fix the UI render lag? or is it just the ending finished render that it speeds up?

Comment: maybe you should turn on "statistics" and tell us, how many vertices you have? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSNQJ.png It depends on your model and (!) your computer. Even the fastest computer of the world would lag if you have a complicated model with 10 Billion vertices...So i would say: it depends...But for sure we cannot tell you with the information you gave us.

Comment: The M1 doesn't support any eGPU's... (M1 here, tried it already btw).

Comment: @brockmann To be precise the M1 _hardware_ supports eGPUs via PCIe using Thunderbolt 3.  Apple's M1 Mac/OS drivers are also perfectly capable of using an eGPU.  Apple simply disabled the ability.